# name node formatting HDFS file not found error in Hadoop2.4.0

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, configuration, hadoop

I have installed my hadoop in /usr/local/hadoop directory

when i try to run the commeand $ bin/hdfs namenode -format  im the getting the error

/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 206: usr/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java : no such file or directory

i have edited the configuration file 
vim etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

fs.defaultFS
    hdfs://localhost:9000

etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml

dfs.replication
    1

Thanks in advance for your answers and replies.

Comment: What's the output of `echo $JAVA_HOME; ls $JAVA_HOME; grep JAVA /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check whether `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly in `.bashrc` file. Use `echo $JAVA_HOME` to check whether it is set or not. If not, set it using

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

Note: After making changes to `.bashrc` file, you'll need to reload it either by logging out and back in or by using `. ~/.bashrc` as pointed out in [*"How do I reload .bashrc without logging out and back in?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518127/how-do-i-reload-bashrc-without-logging-out-and-back-in).

It seems like the `JAVA_HOME` variable is incorrectly set in your `hadoop-env.sh`.
Set `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` instead of `usr/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`. as it is set currently (pointed out by the error).

Use

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"
```

in your `hadoop-env.sh` file.